# Condition check inside rails text_field tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a text field tag in rails view page. Now its written like this..

```
<% if params[:action]== "edit" %>
  <%= f.text_field :id, class: 'form-control', disabled: true %>
<% else %>
  <%= f.text_field :id, class: 'form-control', disabled: false %>
<% end %>
```

Can I write this in a single line.. something like

```
<%= f.text_field :id, class: 'form-control', disabled: (if params[:action]=="edit")?true:false %>
```

I know this is not right. Please correct me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%= f.text_field :id, class: 'form-control', disabled: (params[:action] == 'edit') %>
```

The `params[:action] == 'edit'` already returns `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 2):

You're close.  Try this instead:

```
<%= f.text_field :id, class: 'form-control', disabled: (params[:action] == "edit" ? true : false) %>
```

The parenthesis/brackets need to enclose the whole conditional statment.  That way the statement is evaluated and only `true` or `false` is returned.

[backpackernh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1477964/backpackerhh)'s solution is better - it gets rid of the ternary statement all together:

```
<%= f.text_field :id, class: 'form-control', disabled: (params[:action] == "edit") %>
```

Comment: why not just `disabled: (params[:action] == "edit")` without ternary?

Comment: @backpackerhh mentioned this approach, which is better.